# User has full access to directory, gets 401.1

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Can someone explain what causes this to happen? I am logged into a web server with UserA. UserA has full access to a directory where files are hosted in IIS. When I browse an .asmx file in the directory UserA has full access to using IIS, I get a password prompt. I input my credentials in, and no matter how many times I try, I get a 401.1 access denied. The only type of authentication being used on this site is Windows authentication.

I just fail to understand why a user with full access to the files is denied access to them by IIS. Can someone please explain what is happening here?

This is IIS 7.5. Windows Server 2008

Comment: I take it you've removed Anonymous Authentication, but did you enable Basic or Windows Authentication? What version of Windows/IIS? When asking questions about IIS please be specific about the version you're trying to solve your problem on. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kev, I have updated the question to include the version of IIS/Windows I am using. I stated in the question that the only type of authentication being used is Windows. If this isn't sufficient, please let me know what else I should add to make that clear. -Thanks Dave